# Remove elements from JSON in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to remove elements from JSON String. For example

```
sd <- structure("{\n  \"a1\": \"2022-05-04\",\n  \"inputA\": true,\n  \"valDe\": \"2022-05-04\",\n  \"MainNavBar\": \"V\",\n  \"btna\": 0,\n  \"df\": [\"CRP\", \"AS\", \"OOL\", \"GOT\", \"ANCY\"],\n  \"fd\": {},\n  \"fd.1\": {}\n,\n  \"a1\": \"2022-05-04\",\n  \"inputB\": true,\n  \"valDe\": \"2022-05-04\",\n  \"MainNavBar\": \"V\",\n  \"btna\": 0,\n  \"df\": [\"CRP\", \"AS\", \"OOL\", \"GOT\", \"ANCY\"],\n  \"fd\": {},\n  \"fd.1\": {}\n}", class = "json")

sd
a1": "2022-05-04",
  "inputA": true,
  "valDe": "2022-05-04",
  "MainNavBar": "V",
  "btna": 0,
  "df": ["CRP", "AS", "OOL", "GOT", "ANCY"],
  "fd": {},
  "fd.1": {}
,
  "a1": "2022-05-04",
  "inputB": true,
  "valDe": "2022-05-04",
  "MainNavBar": "V",
  "btna": 0,
  "df": ["CRP", "AS", "OOL", "GOT", "ANCY"],
  "fd": {},
  "fd.1": {}
}
```

Now is there a way to remove elements containing "Input". So expected output to be

```
sd
a1": "2022-05-04",
  "valDe": "2022-05-04",
  "MainNavBar": "V",
  "btna": 0,
  "df": ["CRP", "AS", "OOL", "GOT", "ANCY"],
  "fd": {},
  "fd.1": {}
,
  "a1": "2022-05-04",
  "valDe": "2022-05-04",
  "MainNavBar": "V",
  "btna": 0,
  "df": ["CRP", "AS", "OOL", "GOT", "ANCY"],
  "fd": {},
  "fd.1": {}
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this in R is to read the JSON into an R list, make the changes you want, and convert it back to JSON:

```r
R_sd <- lapply(jsonlite::parse_json(sd), unlist)
sd   <- jsonlite::toJSON(R_sd[!grepl('input', names(R_sd))], auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

The sample string wasn't really valid json, since it contains multiple entries on the same level with the same key name. R fixes this by appending a `.1` at the replicates. However, I am assuming your real data doesn't have this problem.

**sd**

```json
{
    "a1": "2022-05-04",
    "valDe": "2022-05-04",
    "MainNavBar": "V",
    "btna": 0,
    "df": [
        "CRP",
        "AS",
        "OOL",
        "GOT",
        "ANCY"
    ],
    "fd": {

    },
    "fd.1": {

    },
    "a1.1": "2022-05-04",
    "valDe.1": "2022-05-04",
    "MainNavBar.1": "V",
    "btna.1": 0,
    "df.1": [
        "CRP",
        "AS",
        "OOL",
        "GOT",
        "ANCY"
    ],
    "fd.2": {

    },
    "fd.1.1": {

    }
}
```

Comment: Great thanks. How do I remove sqaure brackets here?

Comment: @manup see my update